# Vue component rendering instead of Laravel Blade template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and Vue.js and am trying to setup Typescript with Vue + Blade. Whenever I visit my blade view it will only load the component without any of the blade template.

app.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import ListClubsComponent from "./components/clubs/list-clubs.vue";

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        "list-clubs": ListClubsComponent
    }
});
```

list.blade.php

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
<section id="clubs-container">
    <h1>Clubs</h1>
    <list-clubs :player="{!! $player !!}"></list-clubs>
</section>
@endsection
```

default.blade.php

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('templates.header')

        <main>
            @yield('content')
        </main>

        @include('templates.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

If I don't instantiate Vue on `app.ts` my blade template will load just fine. I only want to use Vue for components that will be loaded into my blade views.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Vue** selector wraps all your content. Try wrapping only the components you want rendered with Vue using `<div id="app">`:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
<section id="clubs-container">
    <h1>Clubs</h1>
    <div id="app">
        <list-clubs :player="{!! $player !!}"></list-clubs>
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

You only have a small amount of markup in **list.blade.php**. You can probably just move the markup into your **Vue** component:

```
@section('content')
<!-- All markup is in Vue component -->
<div id="app">
    <list-clubs :player="{!! $player !!}"></list-clubs>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Edit**: I researched this a bit further for my own curiosity, looks like the blade template may fail to render any content if a **Vue** component is failing somewhere with an error.

Comment: This is what I found is that the `id="app"` is what's causing it but I would rather not have to wrap components with that.

Comment: @JoeScotto I found that the components don't need to be wrapped individually. You should be able to wrap the entire body. I discovered the component failing with an error will cause Vue to replace the selector, in your case `app` with nothing. Check your console for errors.